# Android version of React-Native won't run due to 'Attempted to redefine property 'fontWeight'

Tags: fonts, react-native

The iOS version of my app works fine.  However, when I attempt to run the android version in debug mode, I immediately get this error: [image]

If I dismiss the error, I am able to continue.  However, when I build the apk with assembleRelease, the apk is built, but it immediately crashes on load.  I've double checked to make sure that fontWeight isn't being set twice in any of the components. I've also cleared the cache.

Is there a way to check where exactly this error is occurring?

I've also seen this error: [image]

Comment: majorly this is caused due to duplicate keywords, may be you have declared fontWeight multiple times somewhere, check once by searching 'fontWeight' in whole project

Comment: I've double checked my project.  I do not see any instances where fontWeight has been duplicated.

Comment: maybe duplicate occur in one of your library, please check